# How to print weights and loss at the same time?

Tags: python, tensorflow, placeholder

I just started studying TensorFlow. Now I am confused about how to print weights and loss at the same time.

In this code:

```
x_data=np.random.rand(100)
y_data=x_data*0.1+0.2
b=tf.Variable(0.)  #must be 0.  not 0
k=tf.Variable(0.)
y=k*x_data+b
loss=tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_data-y))
optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.2)
train=optimizer.minimize(loss)
init=tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for step in range(501):
        sess.run(train)
        if step%20==0:
            print(step,sess.run([k,b,loss]))
```

I can print the parameters k, b, and loss at the same time. The result looks like:

```
0 [0.056439728, 0.10114789, 0.014995859]
20 [0.105686955, 0.19681107, 2.4290184e-06]
40 [0.10358144, 0.19799174, 9.633536e-07]
60 [0.10225546, 0.19873528, 3.8206556e-07]
80 [0.10142042, 0.19920352, 1.515299e-07]
......
```

But in another code I have tried:

```
x_data = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, 200)[:, np.newaxis]  
noise = np.random.normal(0, 0.02, x_data.shape)
y_data = np.square(x_data) + noise
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
Weights_L1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, 10]))  # 1 row 10 column
biases_L1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, 10]))
Wx_plus_b_L1 = tf.matmul(x, Weights_L1) + biases_L1
L1 = tf.nn.tanh(Wx_plus_b_L1)
Weights_L2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([10, 1]))  # 10 row 1 column
biases_L2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, 1]))
Wx_plus_b_L2 = tf.matmul(L1, Weights_L2) + biases_L2
prediction = tf.nn.tanh(Wx_plus_b_L2)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - prediction))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(loss)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for step in range(2000):
        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: x_data, y: y_data})
        if step % 200 == 0:
            print(step, sess.run([Weights_L1]))
            print(step,sess.run([loss]))
    prediction_value=sess.run(prediction,feed_dict={x:x_data})
```

Here, I want to use two prints to show weights and loss respectively. But I have the error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_4' with dtype float and shape [?,1]
 [[Node: Placeholder_4 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,1], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

So, here is my question:

How to print weights and loss at the same time? What if I want to print more parameters?

Why do I have this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `loss` depends on input placeholder `x` and `y`, so `print(step,sess.run([loss]))` should be modified as `print(step, sess.run([loss], feed_dict={x: x_data, y: y_data}))`

By the way, you can try `tf.summary` to visualize the weights during training, that's very intuitive.

Comment: That is brilliant. Thanks a lot